# Continent borders kml file

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

Attempting to track down the borders of continents in kml format or another format. Looks like the only thing available open source is country borders. Does anyone have information on this?

Answer (score 5):

For KML with continent outlines here is one with some of the geometry coordinates for the border lines between continents  (e.g. Europe/Asia border, etc.) but they're not labeled:
<s>http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/download.php?Number=236961</s> -- URL no longer available

As for country outlines, there are a number of sources for the outlines in KML. All border outlines are approximations and you have a choice of ones with fewer or larger number of points in the line segments.
Note the first KML source below has total of 24K points for an average of 96 points per country feature and the second has over 100K points with an average of 485 points per country.

For starters here's one shared with Google Earth community in 2006 with 250 countries with polygon borders in KMZ of size ~260K
http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kml/world-country-borders.kmz

[image: World Countries as Polygons. Next generation]

Also a World Country Borders KML with 250 polygons available from the Google Earth Library
<s>http://www.gelib.com/world-borders.htm</s> -- URL no longer available

The country layer can be saved in KMZ file of 1.2MB size (uncompressed 4MB). This has the country flag image inline in the placemark descriptions and also has an optional World Capital layer (as NetworkLink) that can be loaded.

[image: GELIB World Country Borders]

**UPDATE:**

World Administrative Boundaries - Countries and Territories dataset in KML, Shapefile and GeoJSON format is available from here:
https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/world-administrative-boundaries/export/

Comment: I appreciate your reply. However I am looking for continent polygons.

Comment: Updated answer with link to KML example with continents but no labels for geometries. Easy enough to separate.

Comment: Jason I really appreciate the effort. I have seen that kml resource. It doesnt actually contain the coordinate boundaries of the continents. Instead there is a png image which represents this.